# My USB SNES controllers are too laggy - is this fixable?

Tags: retropie, emulation, gamepad

I bought a Pi 3 a while back with some cheap SNES controllers from Ali Express. After setting RetroPie up it worked wonderfully, except that the controller latency is very high and makes a lot of action games like Tetris or any shooter impossible to play.

I know that my controllers were extremely cheap and probably quite low quality. I'm happy to spend a little extra getting some better, newer ones, but I'd like to know if it's actually going to make a difference or if all USB pads will be laggy and unresponsive.

Will a better controller fix my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's the controllers?  A much likelier candidate is your TV not being in some kind of "game" mode to remove post-processing lag.  I've never heard of controllers, even cheap ones, having bad input lag.  If you perceive input lag, it is almost always display latency, not the controllers.

This is usually fixed by using your TV remote or menus to select a "game" mode which removes most of the TV's image processing.